# Print N space-separated integers representing all prime number followed by non prime numbers

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a[100],m,n,i,j,flag,b[100];
  scanf("%d\n",&n);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
      m=a[i];
      flag=0;
      for(j=0;j<=m;j++)
      {
          if(m%j==0){
              flag=flag+1;
          }
      }
      if(flag==2){
          b[i]=m;
          printf("%d",b[i]);
      }
  }
}
```

I am trying to take n array input and print only the prime numbers. But the output which I got for the above code is:

```
OUTPUT:
    5
    7 4 2 6 5
    Floating-point exception(core dumped)
```

I wanted the output to be 7 2 5 4 6 prime number followed by a nonprime number.

Comment: `m%j` that is undefined behavior when `j` is 0. In this case you get an FPE (divide by 0).

Comment: `if(m%j==0){` Thats the problem. You start with j=0

Comment: Oh got it. But can u tell how to print all the prime numbers then followed by nonprime numbers?@SerialLazer@kaylum

Comment: If you're going to use `scanf` (you shouldn't), you *must* check its return value.  Always.

Comment: ok @WilliamPursell

Answer (score 0):

prime number starts from 2, but if your input has 0 and 1 take those also into account while checking. There are better ways to find the prime , for simplicity i used same as OP.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main()
{
    //int a[MAX_SIZE],m,n,i,j,flag,b[MAX_SIZE];
    // use better names for readability
    int Numbers[MAX_SIZE]; // stores all the numbers
    int m,n,i,j,flag;
    
    printf("\nEnter the number for PRIME range:");

    if(1 != scanf("%d",&n))
        printf(" read failed \n");

    printf("enter %d numbers\n", n);
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(1 != scanf("%d",&Numbers[i]))
            printf("read error in loop\n");
    }
    
    printf("PRIMES\n");
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        m = Numbers[i];
        flag = 0;
        if(m == 0 || m == 1) 
            continue;

        // there are better ways to find prime , but using same as OP for simplicity
        for(j = 1;j <= m; j++)
        {
          if( m % j == 0)
          {
              flag = flag + 1;
          }
        }
        // 1 and itself , so prime
        if(flag == 2)
        {
            printf("%d ", m);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You *must* check the value returned by `scanf`.  On input "foobar", the first scanf will not modify n, and the for loop is iterating from 0 to an undetermined number and may overflow the array.  Always check the value returned by scanf.